# Permanent solution for No valid key mapping found for securityToken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-active-directory

I have developed MVC application with the single sign on as an authentication (Company Azure Active Directory) and hosted on Azure as a Cloud service. It was working till now. But before few days, i got the below error in my production

```
No valid key mapping found for securityToken: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/{TenantID}/'
```

Then I searched on the internet and found the below blog

[WIF10201: No valid key mapping found for securityToken](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/musings_on_alm_and_software_development_processes/2015/02/25/wif10201-no-valid-key-mapping-found-for-securitytoken-system-identitymodel-tokens-x509securitytoken-and-issuer-httpssts-windows-net0f44c5d4-42b0-45c2-bf55-d0fea8430d33/)

Then as suggested in the blog, i have fetched the thumbprint and updated my web.config and it worked.

Now again i got the same error today and i needed to do the same steps and found that thumbprint has been changed.

So can anyone please suggest me the permanent solution as it is affecting my production environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the application were not supported signing key rollover automatically. To support the signing key rollover automatically from old project, it depends on how the app integrate with Azure AD.

Based on the description, it seems you were integrate the application with Azure AD for SSO. We can use the .Net OWIN OpenId connect which already has the necessary logic to handle key rollover automatically to authenticate with Azure AD. More detail about this topic, you can refer the document [Signing key rollover in Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-signing-key-rollover/#how-to-perform-a-manual-rollover-if-you-application-does-not-support-automatic-rollover).